# java Regex: how to find real number not preceded by spaces and comma

Tags: java, regex

I have following piece of text:

```
"M -0.6,-0.5 V 256e-17 512.5 h 44.107422 c 20.577609,0 l-3,-4 2,2 -1.9e-12 , 0"
```

I want to make regex detecting all real numbers **except** ones preceded by comma. I can't do this, anyone can help me?

I wrote regex for opposite situation:

```
, *[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
```

it detects every real number preceded by comma.

I'm using this expression for real number detection:

```
[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
```

I've tried to do something with lookbehind, like that:

```
(?<!, *)[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
```

but "Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length" or another error is served to me.

I'm thinking about two different ways:

1. exclude numbers preceded by comma from all real numbers, but idk how,
2. find numbers not preceded by comma, also idk how.

I'm using java.util.regex

Thank you and greetings,
MSZ.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't include statements like "Thank you and greetings, MSZ." . See here for more info: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: You should probably use capture groups for this. Then you can do something like [^\,](real_number), and get the contents of the capture group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex like yours but with the lookbehind converted to an optional capturing group:

```
(, *)?([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)
```

See [its demo](https://regex101.com/r/TiteR8/1). Once you get a match, discard all those where Group 1 was matched.

See [Java demo](https://ideone.com/07ReSw):

```
String s = "M -0.6,-0.5 V 256e-17 512.5 h 44.107422 c 20.577609,0 l-3,-4 2,2 -1.9e-12 , 0";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(, *)?([-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)").matcher(s);
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1) == null) {
        results.add(m.group(2));
    }
}
System.out.println(results);
```

Output:

```
[-0.6, 256e-17, 512.5, 44.107422, 20.577609, -3, 2, -1.9e-12]
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Since my previous regex that doesn't require any processing after matching doesn't work when the commas have spaces after them (*sigh*), here's a different solution that shouldn't take too many steps.

[Link to new regex](https://regex101.com/r/TMNEKO/2)

First use the regex `((?<!([,\-+.0-9]))(?<![0-9][eE])(?<!, ))(\s*[-+]?+)((\d*\.\d+)|\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?`. This will match the real numbers but also includes spaces before the numbers.

Then, to remove the spaces, you can do

```
Pattern
  .compile("((?<!([,\-+.0-9]))(?<![0-9][eE])(?<!, ))(\s*[-+]?+)((\\d*\\.\\d+)|\\d+)([eE][-+]?\\d+)?")
  .splitAsStream(inputYouWantToMatch)
  //You could also use regex like "^ *" to trim it, if you wish
  .map(str -> (str.startsWith(" ")) ? str.replaceFirst(" *", "") : str)
  .collect(Collectors.toList()) //or whatever you prefer to collect it
```

---

The other answer by Wiktor Stribizew is great, but this doesn't really require any processing later and (probably) works just as fine.

`((?<!([,\-+.0-9]))(?<![0-9][eE]))[-+]?((\d*\.\d+)|\d+)([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?`.

If you want it to match numbers ending with a dot like `2.`, then you can use this:

[`((?<!([,\-+.0-9]))(?<![0-9.][eE]))[-+]?((\d*\.\d+)|\d+\.?)([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/J4V8zK/3)

[Link to online regex tester for the first one](https://regex101.com/r/J4V8zK/5) (thanks for the link, Wiktor Stribizew)

It's the regex for a real number but it can't have these things before it

- commas (because you said so)
- plus or minus signs (so it doesn't match `2` in `,-2`
- a digit and then 'e' (so it doesn't match `17` in `,2e17`)
- other numbers (so it doesn't match 3 in ,2**3**)

Also, between the optional plus or minus sign and the 'e' part, it has to either have more than one digit (`\d+`) or (zero or more digits followed by a period followed by one or more digits) so that it doesn't match empty input (forgive me for not using parentheses correctly, those "or"s would have been confusing otherwise.

Comment: This is very good regex, but..
When we consider following string:
M 10,10 20, 20
, there is a space between the comma and the second number.
Because of this, regex catches last number, it shouldn't.
Adding another simple lookbehind solves problem with one space:
[link](https://regex101.com/r/TMNEKO/1),
but is there any way to make regex not detecting number, if between it and the comma is multiple space character?
We can't make lookbehind like that (?<!(, *)), because lookbehinds don't support variable size.

Comment: @MSZ I made a new regex, but it requires trimming the spaces at the starts of the matches afterwards. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Actually deciced to make this that way. Works perfectly.

```
// Parsing points. X'es are detected, when ',' is after number
matcher = Pattern.compile("(, *)?([-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)").matcher(commandList.get(y));
ArrayList<Double> xPointsList = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> yPointsList = new ArrayList<Double>();
// If it's y number, matcher.group(0) looks like this ", 123", Double.valueOf() throws an exception and number is read properly with matcher.group(2)
while(matcher.find()) {
    double number = 0;
    try {
        number = Double.valueOf(matcher.group(0));
        xPointsList.add(number);
    } 
    catch(Exception e) {
        number = Double.valueOf(matcher.group(2));
        yPointsList.add(number);
    }
}
```